# How to architect two level inheritance hierarchy?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I assume a class which has more than one inheritance hierarchies it can be broken down into:
Assume that a class airplane has 4 combinations:

```
1.  Subsonic & commercial
2.  Subsonic & jet fighter
3.  Supersonic & commercial
4.  Supersonic & jet fighter
```

Now my non-object oriented class looks like this

```
Class Airplane {

   Void SubsonicAndCommercial {
       print
    }

    void subsonicAndJet  {

   }

  void supersonicAndCommercial {

  }

  void supersonicAndJet {

 }

}
```

Now I need to break the plane class into subclasses. What’s the most common approach ?
Will this be a 2 level hierarchy ?
Ie 
Iface           Plane
Iface           Subsonic, supersonic extends Plane
4-Subclass      Jet extends supersonic, jet extends Subsonic.. etc

Comment: What do your methods do? Methods do something. They don't express the inheritance hierarchy. They could be factory methods, but yours are return nothing.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, classes can never extend more than one class, so this looks like a job for interfaces. You should make interfaces for Subsonic, Supersonic, Commercial and Fighter. Then you can implement them like so

```
public class SubCommercialPlane implements Subsonic, Commercial


public class SuperCommercialPlane implements Supersonic, Commercial


public class SubFighterPlane implements Subsonic, Fighter


public class SuperCommercialPlane implements Supersonic, Fighter
```

This is probably the best way to accomplish this with simple java hierarchies. If you wanted to tackle this in a more complex way, look into the Entity-Component Model which is explained well in this wikipedia article:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93component%E2%80%93system

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to define *interfaces* for Subsonic, Supersonic, Commercial and Military. Then define classes that implement the appropriate pair of interfaces.

This lets you define methods, for example, that accept a Supersonic interface, that work regardless whether it's Commercial or Military.

You can define an interface like this:

```
public interface IAirplane {
   // Method declarations appropriate for all planes.  
}

public interface ISupersonic extends IAirplane {
   // Method declarations specific to Supersonic aircraft.
}
```

After defining similar interfaces for Subsonic, Commercial and Military, you can define classes that implement the appropriate interfaces. For example:

```
public class SupersonicJetFighter implements ISupersonic, IMilitary {
   // Implementations of methods in IAirplane, ISupersonic and IMilitary
}
```

If some code is common between multiple IAirplane implementations, you could introduce an abstract class.

```
public abstract class AbstractAirplane implements IAirplane {
   // Common methods.
}

public class SupersonicJetFighter 
extends AbstractAirplane 
implements ISupersonic, IMilitary {
   // Implementations of undefined methods in IAirplane, ISupersonic and IMilitary
}
```